# What is deprecated_argument_run meant to do exactly?

Tags: hooks

I found [an odd hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/deprecated_argument_run/) in the WordPress documentation. `deprecated_argument_run` which has this "enlightening description".

> Fires when a deprecated argument is called.

I pretty much figured that much out from the hook name.

What is this hook's intended use?

Comment: "There is a hook `deprecated_argument_run` that will be called that can be used to get the backtrace up to what file and function used the deprecated argument." - [`_deprecated_argument()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_deprecated_argument/). That might help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @sally-cj already hinted at in his comment this is used for debugging purposes, helping developers by notifying them of the use of deprecated arguments in their codebase.

In core this is for example used to alert people of wrong arguments when using the REST API: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/5.2/src/wp-includes/rest-api.php#L177

But you could add your own function to that hook that does whatever you find useful - send a mail, log to a file,...

---

Core uses it inside the (private, so not intended for use by non core code) [`_deprecated_argument`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/5.2/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L4639) function.
And that function `_deprecated_argument` is actually used all over the place in core, for example [inside `get_the_author`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/5.2/src/wp-includes/author-template.php#L27) to give one random example.